# R: Input Dimension Error (bayesm: `rmvpGibbs()`)

Tags: r, exception, matrix, statistics, bayesian

I am new to the **bayesm** package (and bayesian modeling generally).  I have a use case which motivated the current effort: the need for a multivariate probit model that I can wrap in Python.  The **bayesm** package provides just such a method, `rmvpGibbs()`.  I am having some difficulty getting it to run however, because I keep getting an exception complaining that the variance location parameter (`V`) is of "incorrect dimension".

I am just attempting a toy setup with the *Scotch* data housed in the library before moving on to my use case.  Here is my set up.

```
#Capture number of equations (scotches)
p<-ncol(Scotch)

#Capture number of observations
n<-nrow(Scotch)

#Capture the number of covariates (coefficients to be estimated)
d<-1

#Capture regressor data
z<-matrix(d)

#Construct design matrix (kronecker product of d-dimensional array of regressors and Ip for each equation)
X3_tmp<-z %x% diag(p)
X3<-X3_tmp
for(i in 2:n) {X3=rbind(X3,X3_tmp)}

#Capture number of columns k
k<-ncol(X3)

#Convert to long format
scotch_long<-melt(Scotch)

#Capture dependent data
y3<-scotch_long$value

#Capture regressors
#X3<-matrix(1,length(y3),1)

#Consolidate in list
Data3=list(p=nrow(Scotch),y=y3,X=X3)

#Capture priors for coefficients
betabar3<-c(rep(0,k))
A3<-0.01*diag(k)

#Capture priors for variance (start with default)
nu3<-(n-1)+3
V3<-nu3*diag(p)

#Consolidate in list
Prior3=list(betabar=betabar3,A=A3,nu=nu3,V=V3)

#Define initial values
beta0_3<-rep(0,p)
sigma0_3<-diag(p)
sigma0_3[lower.tri(sigma0_3)]<-.5
sigma0_3[upper.tri(sigma0_3)]<-.5

#Define number of iterations
R3<-10000

#Define keep behavior
keep3=1

#Consolidate in list
MCMC3=list(beta0=beta0_3,sigma0=sigma0_3,R=R3,keep=keep3)

#Fit model
simOut3=rmvpGibbs(Data3,Prior3,MCMC3)
```

The call to `rmvpGibbs()` fails with the exception `"V is of incorrect dimension"`.  However, when I check the condition directly (from source)...

```
if(sum(dim(V)==c(p,p)) != 2) pandterm("V is of incorrect dimension")
```

...I find that `sum(dim(V)==c(p,p))` does indeed equal 2 (as expected).  Any advice on why this is failing would be greatly appreciated.  (Feel free to also critique the set up if you feel so inclined.)

Comment: Please note that if you provided the actual input data set "Scotch" to test and troubleshoot with, that would be helpful in reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
nu3<-(n-1)+3
```

To this:

```
nu3<-(p-1)+3
```

Since the definition of nu is:

```
nu d.f. parm for IWishart prior (def: (p-1) + 3)
```

For details, please see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/bayesm.pdf